# Windows phone 8 Webbrowser links are not clickable

Tags: windows-phone-8, webbrowser-control

I'm learning windows phone app development. I took yahoo mail site as sample and using it in the web browser control. I want to understand what settings I need to unable in web browser control to look the web page in web browser control as same as how that shows in Internet explorer on Windows phone. Here the screen shots what I see now

[image]

In the windows phone browser it looks like below -

[image]

Thing I'm  missing here in my app is, I cannot see the 'Search mail' text in the search text box in my app.

The most IMPORTANT thing is that when I click the mail item in the app nothing happens. But in Internet explorer  it actually opens the mail body.

Please guide me.

Comment: Do other pages generally work? Or, do none seem to behave correctly?

Comment: all other links work without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

That probably caused by some functionality of the web page implemented using javascript. Therefore, try to set [IsScriptEnabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.webbrowser.isscriptenabled%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) property to `true` :

```
<WebBrowser IsScriptEnabled="True" .../>
```

That will enable javascript in the webbrowser control which is disabled by default.

Comment: Thank you @har07, I have that setting already set as you mentioned. So I that cannot be as the cause. Do you think there will be something else that I need care about?